# Understanding asynchronicity Subscriptions in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous

I feel like my issue has to do with asynchronous programming as the `subscription` is not running when I would like it to. I usually divide my problem into the user's perspective and the developer's perspective.

**User's Perspective:**

When the user is on the home page and they click on the **Home** navigation button, then the website refreshes. The user does not find that appealing and wants it for if the user is on the home page and clicks on the home page, then nothing should happen. A picture of the navigation is here below. If the user is outside the home page, then (obviously) if they click on the home page then they should be redirected to the home page.
[image]

**Developer's Perspective:**

During the initialization of the template, the code will check if the router URL is `/en/home`. If it is `/en/home` then the href should be equal to `#` and if it isn't then the href should be equal to `/en/home`. Commented code is provided below.

Miscellaneous Service:

```js
// service that does miscellaneous things, one of which is just detecting a url change
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MiscellaneousService {
    urlChange = new Subject<string>()

    // other properties & methods
}
```

header TS component:

```js
export class HomeHeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  currentURL: string = ''
  isHomeRoute: boolean = true
  constructor(private misService: MiscellaneousService, private router: Router) {}
 

  ngOnInit(): void {
    /*
      IMPORTANT READ:
        on every page, we will do a 'urlChange.next()' method to ensure the currentURL is updated.
        I would suppose that the urlChange.next(this.router.url) works but what I am sure of is that the
        subscription does not work as currentURL is always an empty string. I would suppose that this has
        to do with the asyncronousity of subscribe and when it runs. If that is the case, how can I fix this so that 
        the component is always updated to the current URL the user is on?
    */
    this.misService.urlChange.next(this.router.url) 
    this.misService.urlChange.subscribe(currentURL => {
      this.currentURL = currentURL
    })
    console.log(this.currentURL)
    if (this.currentURL == '/en/home') {
      this.isHomeRoute = true
    }
    else {
      this.isHomeRoute = false
    }
  }
```

So how can I make it so the we *subscribe* to any changes in the `router.url`? What do I need to change?

For more reference, here's the part of the template that is the header

Header Template:

```html
      <a class="nav-link" [href]="isHomeRoute ? '#' : '/en/home'">
           home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
      </a>
      <!-- Other code... -->
```

Comment: first subscribe, after change. NOTE: Generally you subscribe in one component and change (next) in another. Typical, in header-component you subscribe, and in another component you change. But, see the answer below, to "observe" the router use the router.events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could observe the `router.events` and filter out the `NavigationEnd` events to catch all successful routing events.

```js
router.events
    .pipe(
        // Only take successfull navigation events
        filter((routingEvent) => routingEvent instanceof NavigationEnd),
    )
    .subscribe((routingEvent) => {
        // Do anything with the URL at this point
        console.log(routingEvent.url);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, but where does `this.destroy$` come from? I never declared it in my header component.

Comment: I've added that, might have been by accident. You could add an component variable called `destroy$` which is a Subject from Rxjs. Then you could call the next value and complete the stream in the `OnDestroy` lifecycle hook from Angular components. Combine it with this `takeUntil` operator, you don't have worry that much about subscriptions not being unsubscribed, thus causing memory leaks from your application, when the component is destroyed. You can leave it out if your handling unsubscribing in another way

Comment: there seems to be a problem with the type of `routingEvent`, do you perhaps know how I can fix it? It seems to be of type `Event_2` so it doesn't give me a URL property... if you can tell me how to fix it then that would be great, if you can't then no worries, you helped a lot!

Comment: Try casting it as an NavigationEnd event. `(routingEvent as NavigationEnd).url`. You'll need to cast it like this because the filter operation doesn't cast it for you and just returns the type which indeed is `Event_2`. If you look at the declaration of `Event_2` it is a type union of different navigation events, including the NavigationEnd event type. You could also include a map operator from Rxjs in the pipe chain like so: `map(event => event as NavigationEnd),` to cast it to the correct type. Then you won't have to do the casting inside your subscription